# Is there a way to await data passed into function so the awaited data is available for export/import?

Tags: javascript, async-await, export, currying

I would like to load data asynchronously from the backend and have some arguments applied into a thunk so that the memoized function is available for import into other areas of my code.  Because await at the top level is not currently allowed, I can't wait for the value to be passed in to the exported function.

For example, I have this function:

```js
const aFunction = (someData) => (props) => {
  // do stuff
}

const someDataFromApi = await getData(); // <-- will not work: top level await not allowed 

const appliedAFunction = aFunction(someDataFromApi);

export { appliedAFunction, aFunction};
```

Then I would have the applied function be readily available for import everywhere (or of course the non-applied version available as well):

```js
import {appliedAFunction, aFunction} from './aFunction'

const cProcess = () => {
  const props = { a: 'foo' };
  appliedAFunction(props)
}

const dProcess = async () => j
  const data = await getData();
  const props = {b: 'bar'};
  aFunction(data)(props)
}
```

Is there an accepted/recommended way to asynchronously apply arguments so its available for export/import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I came up with which allows me to export functions which have been passed promised values.  Its a different answer than to await at the top level, but it works just the same allowing asynchronously retrieved values to be passed and stored so that its available when the exported function is called.

This function allows me to preload promises as an argument, which means I can just export the function before the promise has resolved.

```js
const passToThunkPromiseAsArg = (func: Function) => (
  promise: Promise<any>
) => {
  return (...args) => {
    return promise
      .then((resolvedValue) => {
        return func(resolvedValue)(...args);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        // you might want to resolve errors differently
        return func(null)(...args);
      });
  };
};
```

### Example

Before I export, I pass my function a **promise of a value** instead of a **value**:

```js
// ...
const promiseOfValue: Promise<any> = extremelySlowCalculation();
const appliedAFunction = passToThunkPromiseAsArg(aFunction)(promiseOfValue);

export default {aFunction, appliedAFunction}
```

Then in other files I can call and await or Promise.then the `appliedAFunction`:

```
import {appliedAFunction} from './aFunction'

const cProcess = async () => {
  const props = { a: 'foo' };
  const b = await appliedAFunction(props)
}
```

By the time `cProcess` calls `appliedAFunction`, the promise has very likely resolved, so in most cases there is no actual delay when `b` gets the resolved value.  In the rare case it hasn't been resolved, the function will just await the value.